# Unity Video Player issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, video

I have a single video player that gets different video clips with interaction.
This issue is that, after the first video loads and plays, the video players stop and the end time of the first video for all other videos that are loaded into the player.
The other videos oar of varying number of frames.

How do I get all the videos to play to the end no matter which video is loaded first?

```
StartCoroutine(myPlayTheVideo(myVideoList[myTheOne]));


IEnumerator myPlayTheVideo(VideoClip VideoName) {
    myVideoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
    myVideoPlayer.clip = VideoName;
    myVideoPlayer.Prepare();
    while (!myVideoPlayer.isPrepared)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    myVideoPlayer.Play();
    while (myVideoPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: not that i tried it but try setting the clip to null  after? or make a new player each time.. less of a good idea but at least its new and shiney

Comment: I did try setting the player to null but that did not work either. It looks like the destroy and rebuild is the best option i see so far but am hoping for a better one

Comment: You should at least pass the entire `myVideoList` to `myPlayTheVideo`